# Error: "fewer tokens than expected" while using --update-name flag in plink

Tags: plink

I am trying to update my rsIDs in .bim file by using --update-name flag in plink but getting this error message. what could be the reason of it?

```
plink --bfile updated_ff  --update-name updated_ref.csv --make-bed --out test_updatedrs

PLINK v1.90b6.21 64-bit (19 Oct 2020)
Options in effect:
  --bfile updated_ff
  --make-bed
  --out test_updatedrs
  --update-name updated_ref.csv

Hostname: login1
Working directory: /gpfs/home/bsc08/bsc08856/phs001273_dbgap
Start time: Thu Jun 10 14:23:44 2021

Random number seed: 1623327824
96310 MB RAM detected; reserving 48155 MB for main workspace.
Allocated 15236 MB successfully, after larger attempt(s) failed.
Error: Line 1 of updated_ref.csv has fewer tokens than expected.
```

My updated_ref.csv file looks like this

```
Name,chrpos
rs3793692,chr10_100008436
rs1983865,chr10_100016339
newrs150271620,chr10_100017402
rs10736126,chr10_100025924
chr10_100044928_A_G,chr10_100044928
rs7905091,chr10_100046078
rs6584182,chr10_100055644
chr10_100058710_C_T,chr10_100058710
rs4360594,chr10_10007547
rs927739,chr10_100077732
rs4917817,chr10_100085888
```

while my .bim looks like this

```
1 rs3094315 0 752566 G A
1 rs3131972 0 752721 A G
1 chr1770377 0 770377 T A
1 rs11240777 0 798959 A G
1 chr1834753 0 834753 C G
1 rs72890788 0 836924 A G
1 rs4970383 0 838555 A C
1 chr1840753 0 840753 G A

1 rs4475691 0 846808 A G
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is (likely) that plink is expecting a space separated file for the `--update-name` argument:

```
--update-name <filename> [new ID col. number] [old ID col.] [skip]
```

You've given it a comma-separated file, so it thinks there is only one column, hence the error. You also don't want column names.

Change the sep by:

```
sed 's/,/ /g' updated_ref.csv > updated_ref.txt
```

Or, edit the file in place, and keep a backup of the original named `updated_ref.csv.bak` :

```
sed -i.bak 's/,/ /g' updated_ref.csv > updated_ref.txt
```

Comment: Do you mean cat updated_ref.csv | sed -i 's/,/ /g' > updated_ref.txt 
 according to my data and it will convert my .csv into .txt?

Comment: See update to my post